# Classification of $n\times n$ nilpotent matrix $A$ with $A^k=0$ and $A^{k-1}\neq0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

We know that every $n\times n$ nilpotent matrix A  is similar to a block diagonal matrix of the form with some $r$
\begin{bmatrix}S_{1}&0&\ldots &0\\0&S_{2}&\ldots &0\\\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\0&0&\ldots &S_{r}\end{bmatrix}
where each of the blocks where $S_i$ is a $k_i\times k_i$  shift matrix  of this form
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&\ldots &0\\0&0&1&\ldots &0\\\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\0&0&0&\ldots &1\\0&0&0&\ldots &0\end{bmatrix}
and $\sum_{i=1}^r k_i=n$

My question: If $n\times n$ nilpotent matrix $A$ satisfy $A^k=0$ and $A^{k-1}\neq0$, what's the restriction on $r$ and $k_i$? Or equivalently what's the classification of $n\times n$ nilpotent matrix $A$ with $A^k=0$ and $A^{k-1}\neq0$ up to a similarity transformation？

Comment: @Jack $r$ is in the first matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The have $A^k = 0$ but $A^{k-1} \ne 0$, this must be true in one of the blocks. For $S_i$ to have this property, $k_i$ must be exactly $k$.

So the restrictions are: all $k_i \le k$; at least one $k_i = k$.

Since this can happen with $r = 1$ (simply make $k_1 = k$), there's no lower bound on $r$. For the upper bound: we must have $n-(r-1) \ge k$, so that of the $r$ blocks, at least one is large enough to have the desired property.